# Making two arrays do things to eachother in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm looking to put something like this in my coding

```
@a1 = qw(1 2 3 )

@a2 = qw(5 3 7 8 9 3 5 6 8 2)
```

the amount of items in **@a1** and **@a2** will need to be able to change size

@a3 = each line of @a1 plus each line of @a2 so it would be 5+1 5+2 5+3 3+1 3+2 3+3 7+1 7+2 and so on.

```
with a result of 
6 7 8 4 5 3 8 9 etc
```

Comment: `@a2 X+ @a1` in Perl6 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to have two nested `map` calls:

```
my @a3 = map { my $a = $_; map { $_ + $a } @a1 } @a2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very simply with nested for loops.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @a1 = qw(1 2 3);
my @a2 = qw(5 3 7 8 9 3 5 6 8 2);

my @c;
foreach my $a2 (@a2)
{
    foreach my $a1 (@a1)
    {
        push @c, $a1 + $a2;
    }
}

print Dumper(\@a1, \@a2, \@c);
```

Comment: This works great also, never used the Data:Dumper. Thanks for the answer.